# When is the normality of field extensions transitive?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

I want to answer the following question: Given field extensions $K \subset M \subset L $, when is the case that $M:K$ is normal and $L:M$ is normal implies $L:K$ is normal? In my algebra class we have only considered subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ but I would appreciate an answer involving general fields as well. For example, I try starting with a normal extension $M:K$ and then adjoining elements to $M$ to find the normal $L$, but it seems that $L$ always becomes "too big" in the sense that it is not the splitting field of a polynomial over $M$ because it contains the algebraic element from $M$.

Ex:
$\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\zeta_3, \sqrt[3]{2})$, where $\zeta_3$ is the primitive third root of unity. Certainly $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}): \mathbb{Q}$ is normal, but $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\zeta_3, \sqrt[3]{2}) : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is not (unless I'm not seeing the polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ for which $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\zeta_3, \sqrt[3]{2})$ is the splitting field of) since the splitting field of $p(t)=x^3-2$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3, \sqrt[3]{2})$ (this is what I mean by $L$ is "too big").

So to be clear, I would like to know how to construct our $L$ (such that $L:M$ is normal) and, in general, under what conditions this $L$ is normal over $K$.

Comment: The extension $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{2},\zeta_3,\sqrt[3]{2})/\mathbf Q(\sqrt{2})$ *is* normal. The top field is a splitting field for $x^3 - 2$ over the bottom field. I don't think you're really going to get a satisfactory answer that is not just a translation of the condition into the language of Galois theory.  Just for comparison, when is normality of subgroups transitive? There is no good universal answer to that.

Comment: Isn't $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\zeta_3)$ the splitting field for $x^3-2$? I thought splitting fields were unique? If so then the top field can't be the splitting field for $x^3-2$ over the bottom field. And no, I do not know a good answer to your question other than when the group is abelian.

Comment: There is no absolute concept of splitting field. The whole idea is *relative*. You speak about the splitting field of a polynomial *over a given field*. And any two splitting fields of a chosen polynomial *over a given field* are isomorphic to each other by an isomorphism *fixing that given field*. You have a mistaken idea of what a splitting field means.

Comment: I see, so the splitting field of $x^3-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\zeta_3)$ but the splitting field of the same polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{2},\zeta_3)$ (i.e. for the second case, we have to make the distinction that $x^3-2$ is now considered as a polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, which means the splitting field must include $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$)? But $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{2},\zeta_3)$ is still not normal over $\mathbb{Q}$. What is the condition for this?

Comment: The field $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{2},\zeta_3)$ *is* normal over $\mathbf Q$. It is a splitting field for $(x^2-2)(x^3-2)$ over $\mathbf Q$. You need to completely review this material, since you do not seem to have a strong base of examples that you understand well. If you are taking a class on Galois theory then have a talk with your instructor.